# How to display the rightmost UICollectionViewCell by default in RTL language in iOS

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, arabic-support

In my APP, I have a UICollectionView that display some cells in horizontal. For LTR languages, it works perfectly and displays cells like this:

```
|<-----Screen----->|

| cellA | cellB | cellC | cellD | cellE |
```

When I change the system language to RTL, e.g. Arabic, the layout becomes this:

```
|<-----Screen----->|

| cellE | cellD | cellC | cellB | cellA |
```

I wonder if there is any method I can use to let it display the rightmost cells by default like the following. For now, I need call setContentOffset: to fix this temporarily, but I think there should be a more elegant way.

```
                     |<-----Screen----->|

| cellE | cellD | cellC | cellB | cellA |
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

(This app needs to support iOS 8+)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 9+ You can set `semanticContentAttribute` property of `UIView` for any UIKit controls which is designed/set in your screen using AutoLayout and rest of the thing will be done automatically.

```
yourUICollectionView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, any solutions in iOS 8?

Comment: For iOS 8 we don't have any methods or properties, so we have to scrollToItemAtIndexPath method

Comment: In fact, I just noticed that in some cases rightmost cells are displayed first, and I didn't call any methods to set the contentOffset in both cases, so I'm guessing this may be an undefined behavior.